# Export Different Array Of Object To Excel Using Angular 4/5/6

Tags: angular

I want to export different array of objects to excel file using Angular 4/5/6.

I am able to export single array of object to export.

My problem is like lets say you have 2 array of objects like

```
a = {
  name: "Vaibhav",    
  age: 26
};

b = {
  country: "India",    
  city: "Pune"
};
```

So now I need to export these objects to excel, I am able to export those 2 objects as well but they are appearing in the same line or same row of excel.

I need something like in 1st row name and age & below to that its data & then in the next row country and city & its data.

Not in the same row.

I have used xlsx and file-saver npm packages for this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService{

    static toExportFileName(excelFileName: string): string{
        return `${excelFileName}_export_${new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`;
    }

    public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {   
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, ExcelService.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
    }

}
```

This is my excel service (excel.service.ts) below to which I am passing my array:

I am doing like

```
listArr.push(a);
listArr.push(b);
```

then call to my service excelService.exportAsExcelFile(listArr, 'sample');

Now this creating a excel like :

```
name     age  country  city
Vaibhav  26   India    Pune
```

I want it to be like

```
name     age  
Vaibhav  26
```

and then

```
country  city
India    Pune
```

Comment: You would like country and city to becomes rows and not headers?

Comment: no, country and city will be the headers only followed by its corresponding data but just on the next row not in the same row.